# Spring Data Mongodb and CrudRepository save(): dropped fields from document if not in POJO model

Tags: java, spring, mongodb, repository

I'm using Spring Data Mongodb; yesterday I realized that, after calling standard Repository method save(...), it dropped some fields that weren't defined in POJO model: is there any annotation or annotation option to tell spring data to ignore fields that aren't specified in method argument object? Obviously I wanted not to use MongoTemplate save().

Comment: you mean it's overwriting the whole document rather than updating fields, right?

Comment: That's what save() is designed to do. If you only want to update selected fields, use the updateFirst or updateMulti methods.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to update a mongoDB Document, all you need to use is the save() method and pass the mongoDB auto-created Document _id with the details.